# Hostname configuration for oracle12c on OL7 VM

Tags: oracle, linux, oracle-12c, installation, network

I am trying to install Oracle 12c (for learning/studying purposes)on a VirtualBox VM.  i have set up a VM with Oracle Linux 7.4 and when I setup the wireless/networking aspects during installation I decided to change the hostname from:

```
localhost
```

to:

```
OracleLinux7VM
```

I'm trying to follow along with the [Oracle Installation Docuemenation and I'm on the HostsFile configuration section, it states:](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/oracle-db-12cr1-installation-on-oracle-linux-7#HostsFile)

"""

```
For example.

127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
192.168.0.215   ol7.localdomain  ol7
```

Set the correct hostname in the "/etc/hostname" file.

```
ol7.localdomain
```

"""

In the terminal on my VM, if I execute:

```
hostname
```

it returns

```
OracleLinux7VM
```

but if I cat the /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4

::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6
```

I tried to understanding this through googling and reading the documentation but I'm not sure how exactly I should configure my /etc/hosts file based on my hostname: OracleLinux7VM based in order to successfully install Oracle 12c.  Any and all guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the following to `/etc/hosts` with your actual IP address:

```
192.168.0.215   OracleLinux7VM
```